# $\sum_{n = m}^{\infty}a_n$ converges iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists N \geq n \quad |\sum_{n = p}^{q}| \leq \epsilon$ for all $p, q > N$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am currently reading through "Analysis 1" by Terence Tao, and am unsure whether my proof for proposition 7.2.5 is valid.

Proposition 7.2.5: Let $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n$ an be a formal series of real numbers.
Then $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$,
there exists an integer $N \geq m$ such that: $$\left|\sum_{n = p}^{q}a_n \right| \leq \varepsilon \text{ for all } p,q \geq N$$

Theorems I'll use:

- A sequence of real numbers is convergent iff It is Cauchy.
- Any convergent sequence is also bounded.
- $\sum_{n=p}^{q}a_n$ = $\sum_{n=p}^{i}a_n$ + $\sum_{n=i + 1}^{q}a_n$ for any $p \leq i < q$.
- $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$

My proof is as follows:

First, lets assume that $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent. That means that the sequence
$\left(\sum_{n = m}^{i}a_n\right)_{i = m}^{\infty}$ is convergent. We know that every convergent series of real numbers is also a Cauchy sequence. Thus, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N \geq m$ for which $\left| \sum_{n=m}^{q}a_n - \sum_{n=m}^{p}a_n \right| \leq \varepsilon$ holds for any $p, q \geq N$. We Also know that the series $\left(\sum_{n = m}^{i}a_n\right)_{i = m}^{\infty}$ is bounded by some real number $M \leq 0$.

In the case where $p > q$, $\left|\sum_{n=p}^{q}a_n\right| = |0| = 0$ by the definition of a finite series. In this case, Any $N \geq m$ will do.

As such, the interesting case is when we look at $q \geq p$. Lets choose an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$. We know that there exists some $N \geq m$ for which $\left| \sum_{n=m}^{q}a_n - \sum_{n=m}^{p}a_n \right| \leq \varepsilon \leq \varepsilon + M$ holds for any $q \geq p \geq N$.

$$\left| \sum_{n=m}^{q}a_n - \sum_{n=m}^{p}a_n \right| =
  \left| \left(\sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n + \sum_{n=m}^{p}a_n\right) - \sum_{n=m}^{p}a_n \right| =
  \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n\right| \leq \epsilon + M
$$

$$
  \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n\right| \leq \epsilon + M \\
  \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n\right| - M \leq \epsilon \\
  \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n\right| - |M| \leq \epsilon \\ \Downarrow \\
  \left|\sum_{n = p}^{q}a_n \right| = \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n + a_p\right|\leq \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n\right| - |-a_p| \leq \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^{q}a_n\right| - |M| \leq \epsilon
$$

Since our choice of $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, Our proof is done.

For the other side of the proof, suppose that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \geq m$ for which $\left|\sum_{n = p}^{q}a_n \right| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $p,q \geq N$.

Lets choose some $\varepsilon > 0$ and some $N \geq m$ for which the property above holds.
Lets also choose some $p, q \geq N$. Since the propert holds for any choice of $p \geq N$, it also holds for $p + 1 \geq p \geq N$.

$$\left|\sum_{n = p + 1}^{q}a_n \right| = \left|\sum_{n = p + 1}^{q}a_n + \left(\sum_{n = m}^{p}a_n - \sum_{n = m}^{p}a_n\right) \right| = \left|\sum_{n=m}^{q}a_n - \sum_{n=m}^{p}a_n \right| \leq \varepsilon$$.

This demonstrates that the sequence $\left(\sum_{n = m}^{i}a_n\right)_{i = m}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy,which in turn shows that it is convergent.

proof done.

Comment: The name of the famous author of this textbook should be ‘ Terence Tao’, rather than ‘Tao Terence’. The fourth stated result before your proof is the ‘reverse triangle inequality’ and should instead read as follows: $|a-b| \geq | |a|-|b| |$.

Comment: @Connor_Tracy Actually, that's just a mistake on my part. I used the regular Triangle inequality, and mistyped the + as a -. Also, the order of the name really depends on what culture you're from, but I reversed it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can say $|\sum_{n = p + 1}^q a_n| = |\sum_{n = p}^q a_n|$.

I'm also struggled with the index and still cannot solve it.
But I think in your prove there is something wrong.
Since $a_p = \sum_{n = p}^p a_n$ is bounded by $M$, all we have is $|a_p| \leq M$, and this implies $-M \leq -|a_p|$, so

$$
\left|\sum_{n = p + 1}^q a_n\right| - |a_p| = \left|\sum_{n = p + 1}^q a_n\right| - |-a_p| \not\leq \left|\sum_{n = p + 1}^q a_n\right| - |M| = \left|\sum_{n = p + 1}^q a_n\right| - M.
$$

Comment: > "I Don't think you can say $|\sum_{n = p + 1}^{q} a_n| = |\sum_{n = p}^{q} a_n|$".

I Can't recall saying such a thing, and can't find it while looking at it right now. Can you point me to the line of my proof where I do this step?

Comment: Sorry for that, the word "you" refer to the comment by TheSilverDoe.

Comment: After some search I come across [Cauchy's convergence test](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test).
Seems like Tao got wrong on the index.
Anyway hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition you want to prove can be rewritten as : the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=m}^N a_n \right)_{N \geq m}$ converges iff it is a Cauchy sequence.

Therefore if you know that a sequence of real numbers converges iff it is a Cauchy sequence, then you have nothing to do.

Comment: Could you explain why it can be rewritten this way? I am unable to see it.

Comment: @javajav Can you write the $\varepsilon-N$ definition of a Cauchy sequence in the special case of the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=m}^N a_n \right)_{N \geq m}$ ?

Comment: $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $\exists N \geq m$ for which $\left|\sum_{n = m}^{q}a_n - \sum_{n = m}^{p}a_n \right| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $p, q \geq N$. 

What I fail to see is how you can immediately go from that to $\left|\sum_{n = p}^{q}a_n \right| \leq \varepsilon$ in order to show that the whole proposition is equivalent to showing that it is Cauchy.

Comment: Well, if $q>p$, you have $\left|\sum_{n = m}^{q}a_n - \sum_{n = m}^{p}a_n \right| = \left|\sum_{p+1}^q a_n \right|$ :)

Comment: But the bounds of the series aren't identical to the one in the proposition (p + 1 to q instead of p to q). Or is that ok since p, q are arbitrary?